# Find message ID Gmail API

Tags: python, gmail

so I wrote a small simple function to get message IDs in order to be able to send follow up emails

Here's my code:

```
def find_thread_id(email_to):
    service= get_service()
    user_id = 'me'
    threadlist = service.users().messages().list(userId=user_id, maxResults='20', q=email_to).execute()
    thread = threadlist['messages']
    return thread

thread_id = find_thread_id('in:sent to:partners@ziptransfers.com subject:TEST THREAD FOR EMAILS')
print(thread_id[0])
```

To which I get:

{'id': '185359cbd4ea2a50', 'threadId': '185359c932167922'}

Which is a...dictionary? Anyways I can't for the life of me figure out how to just get the 'id' so I can store it in a variable.

I know I'm dumb but this's been driving me nuts for a while now. Your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you do `print(thread_id[0]["id"])`?

Answer (score 1):

Accessing `id` key in the returning [Dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

```py
# getting the id of the first dict.
id = thread_id[0]['id']
print(id)
```

Comment: Of course that worked, thank you so much,. This confirms my initial suspicion...I'm officially dumb